# Potential energy of parallel plate capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields, capacitance

I am trying to calculate the electrostrictive strain S on a parallel plate capacitor.
For that, I use Young's modulus Y and the formula
$$S = \frac{F}{AY}$$
Since the area A and the Young's modulus are given, I want to calculate F according to
$$F = -\nabla U$$
with $U$ the potential energy stored in the capacitor.

Now, my problem is as follows: From what I know, the energy of a capacitor is
$$U = \frac{1}{2}C V^2$$
I know the voltage V and I also know C of a plate capacitor. However, I still need to get a dependence on $z$ to calculate my partial derivative in the second equation.
But if I use that $$V = E L$$
with L the spacing of the capacitor, I don't get my $z$ dependence at all.
I also know that $$V = \int_0^L E(z) dz$$ but again this gives no $z$ dependence.
I really don't know where to get this dependence from, any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

I added an image of the exercise below. The main problem is that apparently I have to use the formula $F = -\nabla U$, but the $U = \frac{1}{2}CV^2$ is independent of $z$.

[image: Exercise 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the force via $\vec F = -\vec\nabla U$, but this equation is *incomplete* in the sense that it doesn't tell you under what conditions you must change the spacing of the capacitor plates when calculating the energy change. Should the E-field stay constant, or the potential difference? Or the charge?

The answer is that for $\vec F = -\vec \nabla U$ to hold, you need to keep the *charge* constant as you are moving the capacitor plates apart. The equation comes from what is sometimes referred to as the method of virtual displacements. It says that as you pull one of the plates apart, the work done by the electrostatic force must equal the reduction in the electric energy in the capacitor. However, this is only true no external work is done on the capacitor in the process, e.g. via a battery keeping the potential difference constant. So the capacitor must be disconnected from any external circuitry, meaning its charge must remain constant. You can read more about the method of virtual displacements [in this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/560082/171547), and also how to arrive at the same result in the presence of a battery.

Now, as you pull one of the plates away from the dielectric slab, you create an air gap of thickness $z$ between the dielectric and the plate. The equivalent capacitance is the series combination of those of the dielectric slab and the air gap:
$$\frac{1}{C} = \frac{L}{\epsilon A} + \frac{z}{\epsilon_0A}$$
where $A$ is the plate area, $L$ is the slab thickness and $\epsilon$ is the slab dielectric constant. The capacitor energy is
$$U = \frac{Q^2}{2C} = \frac{Q^2}{2}\left(\frac{L}{\epsilon A} + \frac{z}{\epsilon_0A}\right).$$
Finally, the force is found upon taking the derivative, keeping the charge $Q$ constant:
$$F=-\frac{dU}{dz}=-\frac{Q^2}{2\epsilon_0A}. $$
The negative sign indicates that the force is attractive, i.e. in the direction opposite to that you moved the plate in.

There is another way to calculate this force that uses the Lorentz force equation. You can read about it [in this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/702542/171547).

Comment: Thanks. The charge $Q$ however is not given in my example. How could I calculate that?

Comment: @LionCereals $Q = CV$. Note that there is no actual air gap in the capacitor, i.e. $z = 0$.

Comment: Does it make sense that your force depends on $\epsilon_0$ but not on $\epsilon$? I.e. shouldn't the expression be $U = \frac{Q^2}{2}(\frac{L}{\epsilon A} + \frac{z}{\epsilon A})$

Answer (score 0):

V=EL

Where L is the length of the capacitor,is the potential across the capacitor.

V is the potential  at a point, and should be:

$V=E_{0}z$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial z} E_{0}z$

= $E_{0}$

You still need to define $E_{0}$

So just use

$F= E_{0}q$

U is not the energy of the capacitor, it is the potential energy of a charge at a point in space.

Comment: Thanks.  But how can $E_0$ and $E$ be different? I would have said: $U(z) = \frac{1}{2}C(E_0 z)^2 \Rightarrow F(z) = -C E_0^2 z$. Does $E_0 = \frac{V}{L}$ now hold?

Comment: I have just denoted E as $E_{0}$ to identify that it is a constant.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. Does $E_0 = \frac{V}{L}$ now hold or not? If yes, isn't that contradictory to $V = E_0 z$? I think I am missing something fundamental.

Comment: Forget $E_{0}$, $V_{plate}=EL$, represents the potential, across the plates, where L is an input into the equation $V=EZ$ which measures the potential at a point in space, your V in the capacitor equation is the potential across the plates which is EL, not EZ

Comment: Exactly. So $U(z) = \frac{1}{2}CV^2 = \frac{1}{2}C(Ez)^2$ is wrong if $z \neq L$. How can I then ever get a dependence on $z$?

Comment: U in the equation $\vec{F} = -\nabla U$, does not represent the total  energy of the capacitor. It represents the potential energy of a charge at a point. Just use V/L to get E, and then multiply E by q, to find F, no need to go to the gradient equation

Comment: Yes, that makes total sense. However, the hint in my exercise *explicitly* mentions that I should use the gradient equation. It tells me to use $F = -\nabla U$, which is why I got stuck in the first place. I have added a picture of the exercise.

Comment: This answer and the comments are misleading, and the calculation is not as trivial as they make it seem. Not only is $\vec F = -\vec \nabla U$ is fine to use (with $U$ as the capacitor energy), the suggested way of calculating the force, if followed naively, would lead to a result that is off by a factor of 2.

Comment: You are correct puk, I didn't read the question properly and instead answered the force on a charge inside the capacitor instead of the force on one of the capacitor plates.

Comment: I would like to also add that taking my answer to mean Q is the charge of the plate would be incorrect as the E field considered  should be the field generated by the other plate, not the full system